# How to delete emails automatically from Exchange Server?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have a user whose mailbox in the Exchange Server keeps getting full.

How can I set his account to automatically delete the email from the Exchange Server after it has been downloaded to Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Create a rule to **move** all incoming emails to a local PSTs folder and treat that folder as your inbox.  Then it is moved off of the server to the hard drive.  I do this with copy all of the time because the user wants a copy even if they delete it off of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the *Leave a copy of messages on the server* option is not checked.
[image]

Comment: I don't think that someone who uses Outlook in conjunction with Exchange uses POP for connecting to the Exchange. By default the proprietary Exchange/MAPI connection is used.